# MongoDB $regex on email field

Tags: regex, mongodb

if I have a collection with millions of documents and each document contains an "email" field, I know I can set an index on the email field and search quickly.  However, if I want to search by domain name, i tried "/@domain.com$/"  as the regex, but I don't think it's making efficient use of the index.  From the MongoDB documentation, it seems like your regex must have a start anchor like "^" to use the index efficiently.  Are there any suggestions or workarounds?  It seems like storing the email address as a reversed string may actually make the index more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

If querying by domain name is a common use case, populate a separate, indexed `domainName` field and then query that. Just be sure to keep it in sync with any changes to `email`.